# Sharepoint and JavaScript - if one field has different value from second field, then hide third field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, list-form

I am noob in coding in JS and SharePoint, I've to check two conditions in `NewForm.aspx`.

If field, for e.g. "Name" has value "Test", and field "Second Name" has value "Test", then I want field named "Result" to be visible. If values from this two mentioned fields are different, then the field "Result" needs to be hidden.

Comment: Are you using classic experience or modern experience in SharePoint online? All fields are of type "Single line of text'?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code to your `NewForm.aspx` using **Content Editor** or **Script Editor** web part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('nobr:contains("Result")').closest('tr').hide();

        //Show/hide columns based on "Name" column 
        $("input[title^='Name']").change(function () {
            var secondNameVal = $("input[title^='Second Name']").val();

            if ($(this).val() != secondNameVal) {
                $('nobr:contains("Result")').closest('tr').hide();
            } else {
                $('nobr:contains("Result")').closest('tr').show();
            }
        });

        //Show/hide columns based on "Second Name" column 
        $("input[title^='Second Name']").change(function () {
            var nameVal = $("input[title^='Name']").val();
            
            if ($(this).val() != nameVal) {
                $('nobr:contains("Result")').closest('tr').hide();
            } else {
                $('nobr:contains("Result")').closest('tr').show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Similar question**: [Hide a SharePoint list column based on the value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731028/hide-a-sharepoint-list-column-based-on-the-value-of-another-column)

Comment: Hi @analyzer64, did you try this? Is it working for you?